# Safari Background image problems

Tags: html, css

I can get my background image to fill out every browser other than safari on the mac. I've had issues with background images before and I finally want to get this figured out. If there is an "industry standard" for getting background images to fit across all browsers OR to design pages specifically for a certain browser and get certain pages to display based on what browser the user has, I would like to know what that technique is. Also when I open my page up in safari everything is somehow shifted to the left. I've been trying to figure this stuff out for a while and all I've discovered is others have the same problem. If anyone can give me a solution to these problems that would be awesome. Here is the code for my html and css.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css" /> 

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="logo">
<img src="IB SportsTV Logo.png" width="240px" height="180px"/>
</div>


<p class="teaser">July 24th</p>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">

@import url("reset.css");

html
{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
body
{
background-image:url("HomeIBSTVBG.png");
background-size:100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:black;
}
.container
{
width: 73.2em; 
margin: 0 auto;
position:relative;

}
.login
{
position:absolute;
top:50px;
right:100px;
color:white;

font-family:trajan pro;
}
.register
{
position:absolute;
top:300px;
right:100px;
}
.text
{
color:white;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:trajan pro;
}
.logo
{
position:absolute;
top:-20px;
left:100px;
}
.box
{
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:15px;
overflow:hidden;
width:470px;
height:310px;
}
.boxtext
{
position:absolute;
bottom:-300px;
width:470px;
height:310px;
font-size:25px;
font-family:trajan pro;
color:white;
}
.twitterfeed
{
position:absolute;
top:240px;
left:100px;
}

/*memberpage box properties*/
.gamebox
{
position:absolute;
top:150px;
right:100px;
}
.leaderboardbox
{
position:absolute;
top:165px;
left:100px;
}
.viewerspotbox
{
position:absolute;
top:370px;
left:93px;
}


/*picks page properties*/
.mainform
{
position:absolute;
top:150px;
left:100px;
color:white;
font-family:trajan pro;
border:solid darkblue;
background-color:blue;
}
.form2
{
position:absolute;
top:150px;
right:400px;
color:white;
font-family:trajan pro;
border:solid darkblue;
}
.form3
{
position:absolute;
top:500px;
right:400px;
color:white;
font-family:trajan pro;
border:solid darkblue;
}
.form4
{
position:absolute;
top:850px;
right:400px;
color:white;
font-family:trajan pro;
border:solid darkblue;
}
.form5
{
position:absolute;
top:1200px;
right:400px;
color:white;
font-family:trajan pro;
border:solid darkblue;
}

/*Leaderboard Table Properties*/
.tablehead
{
color:white;
font-family:trajan pro;
background-color:blue;
border-color:darkblue;
}
.tablecontents
{
color:white;
text-align:left;
font-family:trajan pro;
background-color:transparent;
border-color:darkblue;
}
.tableposition
{
position:absolute;
top:250px;
left:150px;
}
caption
{
caption-side:bottom;
color:white;
font-size:42px;
font-family:trajan pro;
}
/*teaser text*/
.teaser
{
color:black;
font-family:trajan pro;
font-size:72px;
position:absolute;
left:450px;
top:250px;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a width and height to html, to give body something to inherit:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Works for me all the time with full-page background or videos.